# How to read installed Apps permission and modify a single permission without root in android

Tags: android, permissions

i need to disable particular permissions **for installed apps** like android.permission_INTERNET from manifest file programmatically. Is there any way to do that.

I googled a lot. But i can only read the permissions. How to modify that without reinstall and root. kindly help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you cannot do this.  It would be nice if the Android security model included that capability, but it does not - you can only modify the permission of apps you package yourself.

Comment: Thanks God, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be possible for normal mobiles. We can try this one in rooted mobile only. But still we can get the permissions of other apps in our app without root. For example app, just see [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

> i need to disable particular permissions like android.permission_INTERNET from manifest file programmatically. Is there any way to do that.

Without root? That is not possible. One app cannot change the permissions of another app, even through the device administration API.

Comment: @humblerookie: That does not change permissions of another app. It *does* change whether or not runtime permissions are granted, for any `dangerous` permissions requested by that app. That should not affect `INTERNET` or any other non-`dangerous` permission. It also does not affect legacy apps (`targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower). There are scenarios for which this will be useful, but it does not line up with what the OP inquired about over two years ago (at which time, runtime permissions did not exist yet).

Comment: Agreed, it would definitely not affect the non-dangerous permissions, I misread what OP was looking for :/ .